# Extjs keeping current select items in combo and adding new items

Tags: extjs, combobox

I have a Role combo box which already have 3 item (loaded User Model). Now I need to add the 4th item to the selection but it doesn't keep the current items, and when I add the 4th one, it will be the only item selected in combo.

Is there anyway to implement this behavior ? 
    My grid record is selected like this

```
 doSelectUser: function(grid, record) {
        var me = this;
        var selectedRoleVals = record.get('roles');
        me.getUserForm().loadRecord(record);
```

And then I click the combo box in User Form:

```
 manageusers userform combobox[name=roles]': {
                select: this.doSelectRole
            }
```

combo handler

```
doSelectRole: function(combo, records) {
        var me = 
        var rec = records[0];
```

Comment: How are you loading the record in the combo's store exactly ?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are doing something like

```
combo.getStore().loadRecords(arrayOfRecords);
```

You need to be doing

```
combo.getStore().loadRecords(arrayOfRecords, {addRecords: true});
```

`loadRecords` by default overwrites the contents of the store with the new data.

And to add a simple record to your combo box

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('combo[itemId=theComboItemId]')[0].getStore().add({value: 'aRoleValue', displayText: 'A new role'});
```

Comment: thanks francis. maybe I haven't described my case clearly. In my user Form I can access roles with this line of code                              var selectedRoleValuesFromUserModel = record.get('roles');          now I wanna add item to this list but I cannot access them in my combo handler. I will edit the question a bit.

Comment: @sina I have edited my answer. Hopefully that answers it. I don't know the model definition of a role so I can't be as precise.