# EXTJS: access form items from its child combo box

Tags: extjs, combobox

I have a combo within a from (Panel) and I need to access the "record values (with `record.get('item');`)" of the form in the combobox clickHandler (not just the component but the record). How can I achieve this ?

Comment: You want to refer the form from the combobox clickhandler.Thereby the form values.Is it that you are asking?

Comment: If you are looking for the event to handle then check this link http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-event-select

Comment: yes form.getValues() is the answer for this, but I need to solve another question which has made some trouble for me. here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26655312/extjs-keeping-current-select-items-in-combo-and-adding-new-items/26659615#26659615